# How do you fade in *partially* in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, fadein

Hey everyone. This seems easy enough, but for some reason I'm having a hard time piecing it together. I want to create an animated "fade in" effect, where a div fades from 0 opacity to 50% opacity, and stops.

As far as I understand:

```
var duration = 1000;
$('#mydiv').fadeIn(duration);
```

will fade the div to 100%, with no option of limiting this.

**Is there an elegant way of setting the finishing opacity?**

Comment: I hate it when it requires a long explanation like that.... then all the answers are 1-liners

Comment: The cruel irony is that the more you learn the better your questions get. If he played with the jQuery source code more he'd probably have a shorter question. If he knew about jsfiddle he'd probably have a working example for us of the issue, etc, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.fadeTo();

That's it.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

---

You will notice issues with IE and alpha channels.

These are lovely for FF, chrome and the rest...

```
opacity:0;
-moz-opacity:0;
```

IE expects to see this:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=x).
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you use the [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) method.

Answer (score 1):

use [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) with the second parameter set to 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add the different browser conditional - jQuery will handle opacity in IE and firefox just by using the standard opacity call:

```
$('#mydiv').animate(
    {
        opacity : 0.5
    }, 500
);
```

And yeah, use fadeTo like the others mentioned.

Comment: I actually like your answer more than mine because it's using .animate rather than an configured alias. It's a pet peeve of mine with jQuery that things like $.post exist when they're really just $.ajax with a configuration.